# Edit visibility of TextView on button click

Tags: android, android-intent

I have two Activities (`MainActivity` and `SecondActivity`). My `MainActivity` has two buttons and my `SecondActivity` has a `TextView`. That two buttons will lead to the second activity. What I want to do is, when I click the first button, the `TextView` visibility will be gone. Is that possible?

```
public void hi(View v) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);   
} 

public void hello(View v) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);  
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that is possible.

A simple way to achieve this effect is adding an `extra` to your `Intent`.

```
public void hi(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("textViewVisible", true);
        startActivity(intent);   
} 

public void hello(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("textViewVisible", false);
        startActivity(intent);  
}
```

In your SecondActivities `onCreate()` method you get your boolean value and set the visible depending on it.

```
public void onCreate() {
     ...
  if(getIntent().getBooleanExtra("textViewVisible", true)) {
       textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
  } else {
       textView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can send a boolean value

```
   Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
   intent.putExtra("key",true);
   startActivity(intent);
```

On second button click you can use intent.putExtra("key",false);
Then in SecondActivity

```
    boolean value = getIntent().getBooleanExtra("key",false);
```

Based on value set the visibilty of textview in `SecondActivity`.

```
     if(value==true)
      {
           textView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
      }
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html

```
public boolean getBooleanExtra (String name, boolean defaultValue)

Added in API level 1
Retrieve extended data from the intent.

Parameters
name    The name of the desired item.
defaultValue    the value to be returned if no value of the desired type is stored with the given name.
Returns
the value of an item that previously added with putExtra() or the default value if none was found.
```

Comment: What is the second argument in getBooleanExtra? Why is it set false?

Comment: @speedsir its the default value. look at the docs you will know

Answer (score 1):

Yes, its possible. You can do this by passing a `boolean` value to the `SecondActivity`...if that is true than hide the `TextView`.

```
public void hi(View v) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("isDismiss", true);
        startActivity(intent);   
}
```

In `SecondActivity`...

```
boolean isDismiss = getIntent().getBooleanExtra("isDismiss", false);

if (isDismiss) {
    textView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```